# Access title in webscraping with python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am a beginner when it comes to web scraping with beautifulsoup and python. With the help of yt-videos, I managed to come pretty close to my goal which is to extract the car name of many car listings on a car selling side. However, I am at the last step and do not know how I access the cars name:

This is my code (i just followed the youtube example):

```
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"ads__unit__content"})
contain = containers[0]
container = containers[0]
```

When i excecute:
    container.h2.a

I obtain:

Mercedes-Benz E-klasse All-Terrain E220d 4M All-Terrain

How do I do the last step of just obtaining the car name "Mercedes-Benz E-klasse All-Terrain E220d 4M All-Terrain"?

If I do for instance

```
container.h2.a["id"]
```

I obtain "163525571". But the car name does not have sth like id= before it.

I hope you understand my question. I am very very new to Python and do not know a lot about it.

Best regards

Comment: If you are try to obtain the text inside the element you can use ```.text```

Comment: That actually worked. The problem is that i still do not really understand how to access the different levels of the HTLM codes. Now i want to access the price here: <div class="ads__unit__content__keys"> <div>2016</div> <div>79&nbsp;000 km</div> <div>439&nbsp;847 kr</div> But when i try container.div.text i get the year 2016, not the price (which is 439&nbsp;847 k), which is the next line.

Comment: You can do something like: ```soup.find('div', {'class': 'ads__unit__content__keys'}).findAll('div')[2]``` to get the price?

Comment: I combined everything and added it as an answer :) Please accept it if it helped you :D

Comment: It would be best to read the beginner docs at BeautifulSoup (or google for a simple BeautifulSoup tutorial) , it would avoid converting every attribute seeking into a question and keep SO healthier. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the exact position of the tag then try out the following. Hope it will help you.

```
container.h2.text
```

Comment: Wow, that actually worked. The problem is that i still do not really understand how to access the different levels of the HTLM codes.
Now i want to access the price here:

<div class="ads__unit__content__keys">
<div>2016</div>
<div>79&nbsp;000 km</div>
<div>439&nbsp;847 kr</div>

But when i try container.div.text i get the year 2016, not the price (which is 439&nbsp;847 k), which is the next line.

Answer (score 0):

To access an element's text you can use `.text` attribute. This will return all the text nodes inside that particular node.

To access a specific child's text you can index it like this:

```
soup.find('div', {'class': 'ads__unit__content__keys'}).findAll('div')[2]
```

This will return the text inside the 3rd child of the div which has a class `ads__unit__content__keys`.

Also, welcome to SO :D